# How to create a templated class that has as template one other template

Tags: c++, templates

**Problem Definition :**

My problem is related to Templates of Templates when using typedef, map and iterator.

**Disclaimer :**

Please accept my apologies, I'm new to C++ and my vocabulary is very limited therefore I can not describe precisely my problem in words. I attached my code. I hope it will explain more then them.

**My Code**

I have two type of functions, the set and the get:

```
    template<class T>
    struct SetFunctionClass
    {
        typedef boost::function<void(T)> SetFunction;
    };

    template<class G>
    struct GetFunctionClass
    {
        typedef boost::function<G()> GetFunction;
    };
```

that I can access like this:

```
    void setX (int i)
    {
        std::cout<< "Ciao"<< i*2 << std::endl;
    }

    float getA()
    {
        return 0.1;
    }
    ...
    SetFunctionClass<int>::SetFunction fun = &setX;
    GetFunctionClass<float>::GetFunction fun2 = &getA;
    ...
```

Until here everything is more or less fine, but I would like to be able to insert such functions in a container class, using code something similar to :

```
    FunctionHandler<SetFunctionClass<int>::SetFunction> myIntSetFunctionsHandler ;
    FunctionHandler<GetFunctionClass<float>::GetFunction> myFloatGetFunctionsHandler ;

    std::string methodName("setX");
    myIntSetFunctionsHandler.insert(methodName, fun );
    std::string methodName2("getA");
    myFloatGetFunctionsHandler.insert(methodName2, fun2 );
```

and this is my container class:

```
    template<template <typename > class FunctionClass>

    class FunctionHandler
    {
    private:
        typedef std::map<std::string, FunctionClass > Function_Map;
        typedef typename std::map<std::string, FunctionClass >::iterator Function_Map_Iter;
        Function_Map map;
    public:
        FunctionHandler(void);
        virtual ~FunctionHandler(void);

        void insert(std::string name, FunctionClass fun)
        {
            std::string funName(name);
            map.insert(funName, fun);
        }
        FunctionClass find(const std::string& name)
        {
            std::auto_ptr<std::string> methodName(name);
            Function_Map_Iter iter = map.find(*methodName.get());
            if (iter == map.end())
                throw std::runtime_error("Inexistent method: " + *methodName.get());
            return iter->second;
        }
    };
```

**My Problems :**
My problem lies in the way I template the class FunctionHandler :

```
template<template <typename > class FunctionClass>
```

Many compile errors on templates

and also in the template arguments here :
**NB : Eclipse does not accept this signature**

```
FunctionHandler<SetFunctionClass<int>::SetFunction> myIntSetFunctionsHandler;
```

**Question :**
Could you please explain me how to create a templated class that has as template one other template ???

**EDITED**

**THANKS!**

Comment: **What** is the problem? Do you have compilation errors? run-time errors? something else?

Comment: @n.m.  How to create a templated class that has as template one other template

Comment: @NeilKirk This is too broad a question. I don't know where to start. "Unpack and plug in your computer..." Show a **specific** problem. "I am doing XYZ and I expect ABC to happen, but instead I'm getting IJK".

Comment: you can't write `typedef std::map<std::string, FunctionClass > Function_Map;`, as `map` expects a type as argument, not template-template argument, you should specify what type should it be, e.g. `typedef std::map<std::string, FunctionClass<int> > Function_Map;`

Comment: I think I get your problem, if you want a templated type as argument, it don't have to be template-template paramter. Just put `typename` and compiler will be happy, I mean: `template<typename FunctionClass> class FunctionHandler {...` is sufficient

Comment: @n.m. How is it too broad? He has the code that doesn't work and what he wants to achieve.

Comment: @NeilKirk *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thank a lot !! @PiotrS. It compiled! now I get some problem on the Insert function but it's much clearer now!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a template template parameter but a type:

```
template<typename FunctionClass>
class FunctionHandler;
```

is enough.

you may then use it with

```
FunctionHandler<SetFunctionClass<int>::SetFunction> myIntSetFunctionsHandler;
FunctionHandler<GetFunctionClass<float>::GetFunction> myFloatGetFunctionsHandler;
```

The following

```
template<template <typename > class FunctionClass> class Foo;
```

allows to call

```
Foo<SetFunctionClass> foo; // we don't mention what is the type of SetFunctionClass
```

Comment: `Foo<SetFunctionClass> foo;`  does not work:
`Foo<SetFunctionClass> foo’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined.`
Anyway what could be the use of such signature ?

Comment: I just provide declaration, not definition, so it is normal that it has an incomplete type.

Comment: It may be useful if you manage different types in `Foo`, so Foo may have `FunctionClass<int>` and `FunctionClass<float>` member.

Answer (score 0):

`SetFunctionClass<int>` is a type, as is `SetFunctionClass<int>::SetFunction`.  `SetFunctionClass` is a `template`.

`template <typename > class FunctionClass` is a template argument, not a type argument.

`template`s are things that produce types when you fill in their arguments.  They are not types.  They cannot be used as types within a `template` when you pass them in, they can only be used as `template`s.

If you want a type, pass in a type, and accept a type.